# Setting property value in custom form type

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.2, symfony-2.3

I have an entity Category that has Category children like a tree.
I have a CategorySelectorType that has a few non-mapped fields which 
determine what Category should be set to the form data.

I want to be able to include that CategorySelectorType in any entity and update the mapped property in the entity on which the CategorySelectorType is being used.

Imagine

ArticleType.php

```
$builder->add('title') ;
$builder->add('category','category_selectory') ;
```

So when binding, the category property should be updated with whatever Categpru was chosen using the CategorySelectorType.

I tried doing it in an event lister durint POST_BIND but I get

```
Warning: ReflectionProperty::getValue() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given in /home/neron/sites/zabulu/trunk/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php line 697
```

And it seems to be caused by

```
 UniqueEntityValidator ->validate (object(Category), object(UniqueEntity))
```

Comment: Is `category_selectory` a typo in the question or is it also a typo in your code?

Comment: Yes, it should be category_selector which is just a CategorySelectorType as a service.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand the question and if I do, the correct way to do this would be something like:

```
$builder->add('category', new CategorySelectorType(), array('empty_value' => 'Choose a category'));
```